# ANN Mean Squared Error

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

When using Mean Squared to calculate error, should the actual calculation be done after every epoch or every pattern within a specific data-set?

Thanks John.

Comment: What are you using the MSE for? Backpropagation?

Comment: Yes I am using MSE for Backpropagation

Comment: I know that in practice you usually do the error calculation after every epoch, but I am not sure if that is purely for performance reasons, or if it also might help prevent overfitting. So I'm interested in the *why*

Comment: you should calculate the loss on each minibatch, minimising with regards to the mean of the loss over the minibatch. how do you back propagate without calculating the error?

Comment: In essence, I am feeding forward a pattern within a data-set and then after that pattern I am propagating the output layer and the rest of the network using the derivative of the sigmoid function, then update the weights, finally moving on to the next epoch.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the MSE after every epoch, but use all errors from each pattern in the epoch.

Comment: Yes but the average of the output nodes error for each pattern.

Comment: Average of what?, so 5 output nodes calculate error for all by ((target-desired)^2)/5 after each epoch then accumulate each error after each epoch to give global error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the dataset for which is the greatest member. You need to find the sum of the squared error first which is the greatest member in the dataset equal to zero. Then find the mean square error which is sum of squared error of greatest member divided by N.